# How to remove IndexSetA from IndexSetB in Swift？

Tags: swift, nsindexset

In Objective-C, the `NSIndexSet` can `removeIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexSet`:

```
[aIndexSet removeIndexes: bIndexSet];
```

Is there some way to do this with `IndexSet` in Swift like the `NSIndexSet` in Objective-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function, from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexset/1780485-subtract)

> ```
> mutating func subtract(_ other: IndexSet)
> ```
>
> Removes the elements of the given set from this set.

---

```
var aIndexSet = IndexSet(integersIn: 0..<7)
let bIndexSet = IndexSet(integersIn: 4..<12)

aIndexSet.subtract(bIndexSet)

print(aIndexSet) // 0..<3
```

Comment: works with any set, not only specialized IndexSet http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/type/Set/#func-subtract_-set-set-element